# Books about trust

Tags: social-psychology, personality, decision-making, psychology

Could you recommend me some books that cover trust and how it is developed, what helps us build trust and why we might or might not need it.

I am not interested in the relationship self-help books but a more philosophical and psychological approach to the whole issue, discussions about the development of trust in the recent years and how it is affecting the society, how trust emerges and what factors influence it.

Your help is very much appreciated,

GreenJack

Comment: Blaine G Robbins has not written any books on trust to the best of my knowledge but has published some very useful research papers that could be worth a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only book I know of in that field is Francis Fukuyama's *['Trust: The Social Virtues and the Creation of Prosperity'](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Trust-Social-Virtues-Creation-Prosperity/dp/0684825252)*.

I haven't read it yet, but

- if it is anywhere near the quality of the Fukuyama books I have read, it will be excellent, perhaps even amazing, and
- given what he says about trust in the book I'm reading right now (*['Political Order and Political Decay'](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Political-Order-Decay-Industrial-Globalisation/dp/1846684374)*), I would bet on amazing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Tom! I also found out that ted.com offers some interesting talks about the subject and the relationship between trust and politics.